# Media Player URL options

Tags: streaming, windows-media-player, wmv

Is there a way to pass a start time via URL when opening a video online?
For example:

```
http://www.example.com/newvideo.wmv?starttime=00:33:34.0
```

I've seen different methods for using Javascript or making ASX files in order to give some control over it but I just need to jump to a certain time in the file when it starts playing.  The videos are long and my goal is to make a table of contents where someone can just click a link next to the section they want to view and that's where the video begins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For as far as I know this is not possible and [this seems to suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386383%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that this is indeed the case....

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I think the only solution is to have it come from a streaming server with an ASX file that sets up the link & start time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IE has another language referred to as "time" 
The page needs to be written with some declarations in the style tag just like VML
But very simple with controls you can style yourself, rather than the raw Windows Media Player.

Instead of a link to http url you could write the page with javascipt,
the player tag is like this

<t:media id="bMedia" volume=50 timeAction="visibility" src="xva.wmv" onend="doSomething()"  onmediacomplete="doSomethingElse()"  />

The method you need to use----   bMedia.seekActiveTime(x);  //Locates a specified point on the element's active timeline and begins playing from that point.

learn more here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533611(VS.85).aspx)

Windows Media Player is the program running on these scripts